# BerTopic Model - Visualization ignores 0th index

Tags: python, data-science, artificial-intelligence, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

The [BerTopic](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/) model resulted the below Topics:

[image]

As you can see from the above, the model is finetuned to generate lesser outliers '-1' which has the count of 3 and it appears in the last.

While visualizing the [Topics per class](https://maartengr.github.io/BERTopic/getting_started/topicsperclass/topicsperclass.html),

`topic_model.visualize_topics_per_class(topics_per_class)`

the below interactive visual is generated, and however it ignored the `0th` index, to be precise the Topic 0. The Global Topic Representations are displayed from `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1`

[image]

Is the BerTopic designed in a way that it always assumes the very first index will be an outlier (`-1`), and eliminates it blindly?

Are the generated topics always accessed based on the count size, may be in descending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is posted in the BerTopic [github](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/issues/667) forum as well, and the response from the Author himself,

[image]

by setting `top_n_topics=None`, all the topics along with the `0th` index can be viewed while visualizing,

`topic_model.visualize_topics_per_class(topics_per_class, top_n_topics=None)`